# Solve $x^{f(y)^x}=y^{f(x)^y}$

Tags: logarithms, functional-equations

Let $f:(1,\infty)\to(1,\infty)$. Find $f$ such that $x^{f(y)^x}=y^{f(x)^y}$ for every $x,y>1$.

I tried to take ln twice, then I took $g(x)=\ln(f(x))$ and $h(x)=\frac{g(x)}{x}$ and I got $h(x)-h(y)=\frac{\ln\left(\frac{\ln(x)}{\ln(y)}\right)}{xy}$. I don’t know how to continue.

Comment: What approaches have you taken so far in attempting to solve the functional equation?

Comment: @Nightytime ok.

Comment: Hint: take logarithms once and then move all the $x$s to one side of the equation and all the $y$s to the other side.

Comment: @GregMartin I did that

Comment: That's helpful information to edit into the post. What did you discover?

Comment: @GregMartin should I see a specific function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No such $f$ exists. In fact, even extending the codomain to $[0,\infty),$ the only possibility is the constant map $f(x) = 0$.

---

Firstly, taking logs, the functional equation is $ f(y)^x \log x = f(x)^y \log y,$ and fixing some value of $y,$ observe that as $x \searrow 1,$ the LHS decays to $0$, which means that $f(x) \to 0$ as $x \to 1^+$. This means that either the codomain proposed in the question is incorrect, or that the answer is that there is no solution (which is more boring). Let us suppose that $f: (1,\infty) \to [0,\infty)$ was meant: we can't have the range including negative numbers since then $f(x)^y$ is iffy to define. Note that taking $\log$s over the original functional equation still remains valid, since for any $x > 0, x^{\textrm{anything real}} > 0$.

Suppose that there exist at least two values $y_1, y_2$ such that $f(y_1) > 0$ and $f(y_2) > 0$. Then plugging in $y = y_1$ into the relation, we conclude that for every $x$, $$ f(x) = 
 \left( \frac{f(y_1)^x \log x}{\log y_1}\right)^{1/y_1},$$ and by the same coin, for every $x$, $$ f(x) = \left( \frac{f(y_2)^x \log x}{\log y_2}\right)^{1/y_2}.$$

Equating these, we conclude that for every $x$, $$ \left( \frac{f(y_1)^{y_2}}{f(y_2)^{y_1}}\right)^x \log^{y_1 - y_2} x= \frac{(\log y_1)^{y_2}}{(\log y_2)^{y_1}}.$$ But this is an equation of the form $e^{\alpha x} \log^n(x) = \beta$ for constants $\alpha,n,\beta$ where $\beta > 0,$ which can't hold for every $x$: indeed, wlog, we can assume that $\alpha \ge 0$ (exchange $y_1$ and $y_2$ otherwise), and then no matter the sign of $n$, $x \mapsto e^{\alpha x} \log^n x$ is strictly increasing for large enough $x$, since its derivative is $e^{\alpha x} \log^{n} x ( \alpha + n/x\log x),$ which eventually exceeds $\alpha e^{\alpha x} \log^n(x)/2 > 0$ (since $1/x\log x \to 0$), which means that the equality cannot hold for all $x$ (thanks to Stefan for catching an error in an earlier version of this bit).

We can thus infer that $f$ can have at most one point at which its value is $> 0$. But again if $\exists y_0 > 1 : f(y_0) = c > 0,$ then for every $x \neq y_0,$ $c^x \log x = 0^{y_0} \log y_0 = 0$, which contradicts the elementary fact that $c^x \log x > 0$ over $(1,\infty)$ if $c > 0.$

It follows then that the only candidate is $f(x) =0$ identically. This does satisfy the original functional equation, and we're done.

Comment: The equality above the e^(alpha×x).. why we have logx? Shouldn't we have (logx)^(y2-y1)?

Comment: @StefanSolomon Ah good catch. I'll amend this later, but note that the point still stands: for $\alpha \ge 0,$ and any $n, e^{\alpha x} \log^n x$ is *eventually* strictly increasing, so the equality cannot hold for all $x$ large enough, supplying the contradiction.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that this function does not exist. Brethlosze has made a great argument and I agree with everything in it, but the answer just does not seem to work. Here is an attempt of showing a continuously differentiable $f$ does not exist. It should also show a $f$ that is continuously differentiable on any interval cannot exist. This would mean $f$ must be quite pathological, if it exists at all.

From the identity (*): $\ln\ln x + x \ln f(y) = \ln\ln y + y \ln f(x)$ for all $x, y \in (1, \infty)$, we can define a bivariate function $F: (1, \infty)^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ by
$$F(x, y) = \ln\ln x + x \ln f(y) = \ln\ln y + y \ln f(x).$$
It is twice continuously differentiable:
$$\nabla F(x, y) = \pmatrix{\partial_x (\ln\ln x + x \ln f(y)) \\ \partial_y (\ln\ln y + y \ln f(x))} = \pmatrix{\frac{1}{x \ln x} + \ln f(y) \\ \frac{1}{y \ln y} + \ln f(x)},$$
and each component again has continuous partial derivatives. Then, the mixed partial derivatives must be equal:
$$\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)} = \partial_x \partial_y F(x, y) = \partial_y \partial_x F(x, y) = \frac{f'(y)}{f(y)}.$$
So we can define $G(x, y) = \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)} = \frac{f'(y)}{f(y)}$. This $G$ is independent of $y$ and of $x$, so it is a constant, say $A$. This implies $f(x) = e^{Ax+B}$ for some constant $B$. However, when you plug this into the identity (*), it fails:
$$\text{LHS} = \ln \ln x + x (Ay + B) = \ln \ln y + y (Ax + B) = \text{RHS},$$
simplifying into
$$\ln \ln x + B x = \ln \ln y + B y \text{ for all } x, y \in (1, \infty),$$
but no constant $B$ can make this identity hold.

Comment: In the same vein as my comments to Brethlosze's answer, you can complete this argument as follows: note that in order to write the equation involving $\log f(x), \log f(y),$ you need to assume that both are positive. So, if we suppose that there is some interval $(a,b) \subset (1,\infty)$ over which $f$ is positive, then your argument yields a contradiction. This means that every interval contains a root of $f$, i.e., that the roots of $f$ are dense on $(1,\infty)$. Combining this with the continuity of $f$ yields that $f$ must thus be $0$ everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved by replacing $y$ by $x+h$ and taking the limit, since this holds for every $x,y$.

Take logarithms twice:
$$
\ln\ln x+x \ln f(y) = \ln\ln y+y \ln f(x)
$$

Rearrange differentials:
$$
x{\ln f(y)-\ln f(x) \over y-x} = {\ln\ln y-\ln\ln x \over y-x} + \ln f(x)
$$

Divide by $1/x$ terms:
$$
{1\over x}{\ln f(y)-\ln f(x) \over y-x}-{1\over x^2}\ln f(x) = {1\over x^2}{\ln\ln y-\ln\ln x \over y-x} 
$$

Take the limit $y\to x$:
$$
\left( {1\over x}{\ln f(x)} \right)' = {1\over x^2}\left({\ln\ln x}\right)' = \frac1{x^3\ln x}.
$$

Finally, solving for $f$:
$$
f(x) = \exp \biggl( x \int^x \frac1{z^3 \ln z}\,dz +c\biggr)
$$
With the [Exponential Integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral) function $\text{Ei}$, a better expression (but harder to justify) is obtained:
$$
f(x)=\exp \bigl( x \mathop{\rm Ei}(-2 \ln(x)) \bigr).
$$

Note the original expression implies $\lim_{x\to1^+}f(x)=0$, and since $\lim_{x\to1^+}\text{Ei}(x)=-\infty$, then $f(1)=0$ for the previous formulas.

Comment: They should match with $a=1$. Check the graph at [wolframalpha.com](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=e%5E%28x+Ei%28-2+ln%28x%29%29%29+from+x+1+to+10) using the $Ei(x)$ function to calculate.

Comment: Fixed comment: the integral $\int_a^x \frac{dz}{z^3\ln(z)}$ diverges as $a\to 1$, but $f(x)$’s graph approaches that of  $x=1$. Besides these values, the [graphs](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/qn9xleugl1) do not seem to match fully.

Comment: I followed your method and I agree with every step but there just seems to be something wrong the result. Other than what Tyma has mentioned, the range $f(x)$ seems wrong: it's $(0, 1)$?

Comment: Plugging the answer back into the original function equation doesn't verify the answer (computationally the two sides are different).

Comment: (Long comment) I was wondering where the issue in this answer lies. (Of course the $\mathrm{Ei}$ bit is iffy: this is only defined for positive arguments, and $-2\log x < 0$ for $x > 1$). Nevertheless, if we assume $f > 0$ over some interval $(x_1, x_2)$, and just define $I(x) = \int_{x_3}^x 1/(t^3 \log t)$ for some $x_3$ in this interval, then following the analysis yields a one-parameter family of candidates $f(x) = A\exp( xI(x)),$ where $A = f(x_3).$ The question then becomes what value(s) of $A$ are valid. Dumping this form into the log of the functional equation,

Comment: (contd.) we get $A^x \exp( xy I(y)) \log x = A^y \exp(xy I(x)) \log y.$ Now the subtlety is that for $y = x + \varepsilon, xy(I(y) - I(x)) - (\log\log y - \log\log x)$ vanishes to the first order, giving a relation of the form $ A^{\varepsilon} = \exp( \varepsilon^2 \varphi(x) + O(\varepsilon^3)),$ which can't work: if $A \neq 1,$ then the LHS has first order dependence, and the RHS doesn't, while if $A = 1,$ the the LHS doesn't have second order behaviour, while the RHS does. One concludes that no $A > 0$ is valid, which means that $f = 0$ *somewhere* in $(x_1,x_2)$ (i.e., violating $f> 0$)

Comment: (contd.) But $x_1$ and $x_2$ are arbitrary, so this means that the set of roots of $f$ is dense in $(1,\infty)$. Now observing that $f$ must be continuous using $f(y) = f(x)^{y - x} (\log y/\log x)^{1/x},$ we conclude that $f = 0$ everywhere. Upshot being that the approach in this answer does lead to the conclusion that the only possibility is that $f = 0$, but it takes more work than is in the answer to get there.